# Getting the NPM ng-circle-progress Component to work in Angular 16?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, svg, ng-circle-progress

Trying to get the [NG Circle Progress component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-circle-progress) to work in Angular 16.

[This is the Stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-f5fawl?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

This is the template configuration.

```
  <circle-progress name="A" [options]="optionsA" [renderOnClick]="false" class="copy"
  (click)="copyOptions($event, optionsA)"></circle-progress>
```

And this are the component options in `main.ts`.

```
  optionsA = {
    percent: 85,
    radius: 60,
    showBackground: false,
    outerStrokeWidth: 10,
    innerStrokeWidth: 5,
    subtitleFormat: false, // clear subtitleFormat coming from other options, because Angular does not assign if variable is undefined.
    startFromZero: false,
  };
```

And the module configuration is specified according to the README.md.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgCircleProgressModule.forRoot({
      radius: 100,
      outerStrokeWidth: 16,
      innerStrokeWidth: 8,
      outerStrokeColor: '#78C000',
      innerStrokeColor: '#C7E596',
      animationDuration: 300,
    }),
  ],
```

The module configuration produces the following error.

```
Type 'ModuleWithProviders<NgCircleProgressModule>' is not assignable to type 'readonly any[] | Type<any>'.(2322)
(alias) class NgCircleProgressModule
import NgCircleProgressModule
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Where do you add the `NgCircleProgressModule.forRoot()` ?

Comment: I updated the question with the markup so that its easier to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XXModule.forRoot()` methods return providers, this call belongs into the provider part of the component configuration.

Also you'll need to keep the import.

So it should look like following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, NgCircleProgressModule],
  providers: [
    (NgCircleProgressModule.forRoot({
      radius: 100,
      outerStrokeWidth: 16,
      innerStrokeWidth: 8,
      outerStrokeColor: '#78C000',
      innerStrokeColor: '#C7E596',
      animationDuration: 300,
    }) as ModuleWithProviders<NgCircleProgressModule>).providers!,
  ],
  template: `
  <circle-progress name="A" [options]="optionsA" [renderOnClick]="false" class="copy"
  (click)="copyOptions($event, optionsA)"></circle-progress>
`,
})
```

In addition, the [circle-progress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-circle-progress) component's options are typed as `CircleProgressOptions` instead of `CircleProgressOptionsInterface` and this implementation is more strict, therefore `optionsA` needs to have all the properties of `CircleProgressOptions`.  They can be added like this:

```
  optionsA: CircleProgressOptions = {
    ...this.options,
    percent: 85,
    radius: 60,
    showBackground: false,
    outerStrokeWidth: 10,
    innerStrokeWidth: 5,
    subtitleFormat: false, // clear subtitleFormat coming from other options, because Angular does not assign if variable is undefined.
    startFromZero: false,
  };
```

[Here's a working implementation.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rkwa4c?file=src%2Fmain.ts).

Comment: Matthieu I figured your question was a "Hint" so I tried providers ... but that creates another problem ... https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rkwa4c?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: Please see my edit, I forgot the providers were nested !

Comment: Matthieu I tried that edit, but now it has this error ... https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rkwa4c?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: You need to assert your option input :  `optionA = { ... } as CircleProgressOptions`

Comment: Isn't this what the `importProvidersFrom` method is for?  https://angular.io/api/core/importProvidersFrom

Comment: No, the compiler is complaining because optionA doesn't compily to the interface `CircleProgressOptions `.

Comment: That part is weird ... I typed `optionsA` with `CircleProgressOptions`, as can be seen in the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rkwa4c?file=src%2Fmain.ts), and `optionsA` do conform to the interface, which makes sense because all the options in the [interface](https://github.com/bootsoon/ng-circle-progress/blob/e1eb59dd442e2909e49ff060cdf9a9d27fefd9ab/projects/ng-circle-progress/src/lib/ng-circle-progress.component.ts#L5) are optional.

Comment: `CircleProgressOptions ` is a class that extends `CircleProgressOptionsInterface`. The class has no optional fields.

Comment: Matthieu - The `CircleProgressOptions` class implements the `CircleProgressOptionsInterface`.  If you look at the current Stackblitz implementation you'll see that the `optionsA` object conforms to hte semantics of the `CircleProgressOptions` class.

Comment: Download the project, you'll see that `optionsA` does not match. You should probably create a class and change the values.

Comment: Matthieu - I see what you mean.  I created a pure typescript stackblitz with just the options implementations and I get the same error.  Strange.  I really thought that implementing an interface with the defined types as optional would mean that they are optional on the corresponding implementation as well ...https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-s7a657?file=index.ts

Comment: Since they are required in the class, that changes everything.

Comment: Indeed :).  Just when I thought I knew how to code ... :)

Comment: Happens to every experienced developper from time to time 

Comment: It almost seems like this is a Typescript bug ... Because the class conforms to the interface ... without really conforming to the interface ....

Comment: It does conform to the interface but it's stricter.

Comment: I guess we can view it both ways.  I took the view that the interface is not properly implemented since I'm viewing the interface as a contract that has certain semantics and that if the interface is implemented then whatever implements it should offer the same contract to clients ... I created a [Typescript issue for it](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55321)

Comment: It's not a bug, your issue is going to get close since it is the correct behaviour.

Comment: I agree - If people want the looser specification they should just type according to the interface and not the class, which is what the circle progress implementation should be doing ...

Comment: [I opened an issue on the ng-circle-progress repository](https://github.com/bootsoon/ng-circle-progress/issues/203)

Comment: I fixed the Stackblitz by expanding the `this.options` parameter into `optionsA`.  I updated the answer with this and checked off and upvoted the question.  Thanks again for all the insight Matthieu!

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler any idea why it's not working with onPush ?